# Why can we expand terms with random variables in the variance formula?

Tags: variance, random-variable, expected-value

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{E}}$$\newcommand{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}$In the proof for showing the alternative formula for variance, i.e. $$\E[(X - \mu)^2] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$$

I typically see the following step.

$$\E[(X - \mu)^2] = E[X^2 - 2\mu X + \mu^2]$$

My question is *why* can we expand $(X-\mu)^2?$ It's not immediately clear in my mind since a random variable in statistics is a function $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, not a scalar like $\mu$.

Comment: The values a random variable has are real numbers and therefore satisfy all the familiar algebraic relationships of real numbers.  Indeed, the "$\mu$"in the expression "$(X-\mu)^2$" *must* be understood not as a scalar but as a constant function defined on $\Omega.$  This is so familiar that mathematical notation rarely distinguishes this function from the number $\mu$ itself.

Comment: Hi @whuber! I understand your point about $X(\omega)$ only taking on real numbers, but can you elaborate on $\mu$ being a "constant function defined on $\Omega$"? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: It comes down to this: exactly how can one go about defining the difference (or sum or product etc) between a *function* and a *number*?  The standard answer is to extend operations defined on the range of a function (the real numbers in this case) by operating pointwise on the values of functions and to embed the range into this algebra of functions by identifying the range with the constant functions.  This is so obvious that it's rarely even pointed out in elementary texts that some such mechanism is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really just a reflection of the fact that the algebraic rules for real numbers also hold for functions mapping onto the real numbers.  When dealing with random variables, algebraic functions of random variables are considered to be new random variables defined using the corresponding algebraic expression for their outcome under a particular element of the sample space.  This leads to a correspondence between the defined form for a particular element of the sample space and the relationships between the random variables themselves.

---

**Formal demonstration:** To see this, we can show formally how the property is derived in the present case.  As you have noted in your question, your random variable is a function $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  For any constant value $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, the corresponding object $D = (X-\mu)^2$ is another random variable defined by:

$$D(\omega) = (X(\omega)-\mu)^2 \quad \quad \quad \text{for all } \omega \in \Omega.$$

(Alternatively, we could define the constant function $\mu_F: \Omega \mapsto \mu$ and then use $\mu_F(\omega)$ instead of the constant.)  Using standard algebraic rules, for any $\omega \in \Omega$ you then have:

$$D(\omega) = (X(\omega)-\mu)^2 = X(\omega)^2 - 2 \mu X(\omega) + \mu^2.$$

Thus, we can write the random variable equivalently as:

$$D(\omega) = X(\omega)^2 - 2 \mu X(\omega) + \mu^2 \quad \quad \quad \text{for all } \omega \in \Omega.$$

Since this holds for all $\omega \in \Omega$, this means that we can write this random variable as $D = X^2 - 2 \mu X + \mu^2$.  This establishes the equivalence of the two forms inside the expected value in your expressions.